# Heroku node.js app crashing

Tags: node.js, heroku

I try deploying node.js via Heroku. 
However there are Application ERROR.

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 322 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  v6.8.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   3.10.8
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version v6.8.1 via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.8.1...
remote:        npm 3.10.8 already installed with node
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── cookie@0.3.1
remote:        ├── ejs@2.5.2
remote:        └── jade@1.11.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 14.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v9
remote:        https://sawartc.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/sawartc.git
   7d9216c..973d8ba  master -> master
sawamuratakashikan-no-MacBook-Pro:node sawamuratakahiro$ heroku open
```

This deploy may be succeeded.

but it happen application error.

And then, this is heroku logs.

```
2016-10-24T15:25:07.521109+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T15:25:07.500572+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-10-24T17:10:24.410630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-24T17:10:26.487227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-10-24T17:10:29.973959+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:10:29.973971+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2016-10-24T17:10:29.973972+00:00 app[web.1]: > node sampleapp.js
2016-10-24T17:10:29.973973+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:10:30.163591+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
2016-10-24T17:11:26.793014+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2016-10-24T17:11:26.755681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-10-24T17:11:26.755825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-10-24T17:11:26.903907+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2016-10-24T17:11:26.919339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T20:08:20.748447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-24T20:08:22.155076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-10-24T20:08:24.669537+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2016-10-24T20:08:24.669514+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T20:08:24.669538+00:00 app[web.1]: > node sampleapp.js
2016-10-24T20:08:24.669539+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T20:08:24.786219+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
2016-10-24T20:09:22.309836+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-10-24T20:09:22.309836+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-10-24T20:09:22.399015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-10-24T20:09:22.406141+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-25T01:40:39.946449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-25T01:40:41.519699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-10-25T01:40:43.843569+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-25T01:40:43.843581+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2016-10-25T01:40:43.843581+00:00 app[web.1]: > node sampleapp.js
2016-10-25T01:40:43.843582+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-25T01:40:43.943591+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
2016-10-25T01:41:42.057140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-10-25T01:41:42.057234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-10-25T01:41:42.172614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-10-25T01:41:42.207278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-25T03:42:53.015078+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2e44739 by 
2016-10-25T03:42:53.015138+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by 
2016-10-25T03:42:53.546204+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-25T03:42:53.546194+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-25T03:42:53.630591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-25T03:42:54.901534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-10-25T03:42:57.073592+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-25T03:42:57.073608+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2016-10-25T03:42:57.073608+00:00 app[web.1]: > node sampleapp.js
2016-10-25T03:42:57.192757+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
2016-10-25T03:42:57.073609+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-25T03:43:55.242924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-10-25T03:43:55.242924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-10-25T03:43:55.403793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-10-25T03:43:55.418227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-25T03:43:55.419140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-25T03:43:56.641767+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-10-25T03:43:58.885658+00:00 app[web.1]: > node@1.0.0 start /app
2016-10-25T03:43:58.885646+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-25T03:43:58.885659+00:00 app[web.1]: > node sampleapp.js
2016-10-25T03:43:58.885663+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-25T03:43:58.988687+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
2016-10-25T03:44:20.981992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=sawartc.herokuapp.com request_id=19ae4ca5-679f-4ef1-9e5c-9408dd6963b2 fwd="219.117.193.211" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-25T03:44:57.129700+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-10-25T03:44:57.129700+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-10-25T03:44:57.244921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-25T03:44:57.267311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

So, what should I do to deploy this node.js app.

Comment: What happens when you run it locally?

Answer (score 17):

From the logs, it seems that you are binding to dynamic port `1337`, however this runs locally, Heroku allows you to use only port `8080`. Best approach to define your port is:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
```

So Heroku uses its port, while running your code in local, you still can use 1337 port.

Comment: I am having the same issue. But port 8080 also not working. Can there be some other reason ?

Comment: the env is case sensitive, make sure you are using `PORT`, not `port`. Never set the PORT env, let heroku do it for you

Answer (score 1):

You need a start script in your package.json file. Something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the default "start" script. I think on free dyno, heroku only allow to run "npm start". However the default start script is attached with dev server.

So in your package.json file, replace the command in "start" script with "serve -s build" and it works just fine.